# AWS IoT basicPubSub.py example - clarification on certificates (CLI)

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, mqtt, iot

I am been trying to get AWS IoT working and just keep hitting problems, errors and not getting anywhere. I am trying to use the AWS IoT basicPubSub.py script to test the connection, but getting an error:

```
 ssl.SSLError: unknown error (_ssl.c:3946)
```

I have been through all the certificates several times, but want to check/fully understand if I can pull the rootCAFile, certfile and privatekey from the command line utility and/or from the IAM interface? I have download each piece of information and stored in local files.

```
python basicPubSub.py -e <endpoint> -r <rootCAFilePath> -c <certFilePath> -k <privateKeyFilePath>
```

The main aim is just to ensure everything is correct or I have another problem something else? Is there a way to test each certificate to ensure each file is correct and has the right information?

Comment: I recommend you try using a client such as [MQTT.fx](https://mqttfx.jensd.de/) to check your certificate and AWS IoT policy configuration. Once you have this sorted out then try the python example.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how I managed to fix this problem, I tried the following items to fix the problem:

1. Re-created all the certificates
2. Re-installated CLI using sudo
3. Installed ssl (sudo apt-get install -y libssl-dev)

I going to do a fresh installation on my RPi and repeat the steps to understand how this was resolved and fixed.